# Difficulty Comparing a variable substring to a string

Tags: batch-file

I have a very long string for use as a map. It is about 50 characters (10 for my example though). I also have a string that I want to use as a number that represents the players position on the map string:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET map=CGWGWBBBTB
SET playerposition=1
```

So if `playerposition` was 3 I would want to receive `W` from this next line of code:

```
%map:~%playerposition%,1%
```

It seems I can not retrieve the `playereposition` variable like that.

Comment: `!map:~%playerposition%,1!` with Delayed Expansion enabled, or `call <any command> %%map:~%playerposition%,1%%` without. This management is explained at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) although the question is not the same...

Comment: @Aacini Thanks! This was very helpful! Would upvote  if that were a thing for comments...

Comment: Well, you may upvote the linked answer... **`;)`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
@ECHO OFF
SET map=CGWGWBBBTB
SET playerposition=1
CALL SET playereposition=%%map:~%playerposition%,1%%
SET play
SET playerposition=2
CALL SET playereposition=%%map:~%playerposition%,1%%
SET play
SET playerposition=3
CALL SET playereposition=%%map:~%playerposition%,1%%
SET play
```

You could also use a subroutine:

```
SET playerposition=4
CALL :setsubstr playereposition map %playerposition% 1
SET play

GOTO :EOF

:setsubstr
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "return=!%2:~%3,%4!"
endlocal&SET "%1=%return%"
GOTO :EOF
```

Here, the temporary variable `return` is used to contain the substring-from-3rd-parameter-length-4th-parameter-of the string second-parameter into variable-name first-parameter.

The `endlocal&...` disposes of the temporary variable and uses a parsing trick to assign the value to `%1`.

Note that using this approach also allows the routine to be made "smart" by allowing (with changes) an omitted 4th parameter to default to 1, for instance.

Note also in all of this that position-counting in a string starts from `0`, not `1`.